# match partial value between 2 columns from different dataframes using with spacy

Tags: pandas, dataframe, spacy

I have two data frames df1 and df2 as shown below:

**Df1:**

```
           movie_name correct_id  year
0             birdman        N/A  2010
1   avengers: endgame        N/A  2020
2            deadpool        N/A  2013
3        bla 208-2020        N/A  2018
4  once upon deadpool        N/A  2020
```

**Df2: data frame of reference**

```
               movie_ref     id
0               birdmans  19876
1          The bird King  20807
2  The avengers: endgame  13978
3   once upon a deadpool  49999
4           bla 207-2020  45678
5                bla 208  66097
```

**Expected Result:**

```
           movie_name correct_id  year  
0             birdman      19876  2010
1   avengers: endgame      13978  2020
2            deadpool        N/A  2013
3        bla 208-2020      66097  2018
4  once upon deadpool      49999  2020
```

Please how do I merge two dataframes based on partial string match using **spacy**?

**NB**: The movie's name not exactly the same/ and the two dataframes have different lengths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `difflib` library to find the closet match and then you can create a `mapping dict` to fetch the required values:

```
import difflib

df2.movie_ref = df2.movie_ref.apply(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(
    x, df1.movie_name.values, n=1, cutoff=.6)).explode()
df1['correct_id'] = df1.movie_name.map(dict(df2.dropna().values))
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
           movie_name  correct_id  year
0             birdman     19876.0  2010
1   avengers: endgame     13978.0  2020
2            deadpool         NaN  2013
3        bla 208-2020     66097.0  2018
4  once upon deadpool     49999.0  2020
```

*NOTE*: change the `cutoff` value according to your requirement.

Comment: Thks but I need to use spacy.

Comment: Why do you need to use spaCy? spaCy is honestly not the best fit for very short texts like this.